# GPO Office Installation - Script runs on PC, How could I get it to appear when a user logs in?

Tags: installation, scripting, group-policy, microsoft-office-2010

I currently have a GPO created that installs Office 2010 for users during startup of the PC.

This script is set to run for specific PCs.  Is there any way that I can get the script to appear and run on screen when a user logs in? 
I want the Office installation progress to appear on screen as the installation appears to be completely silent.

I realise I could have made the installation user specific.  However, I was wondering if it is possible to make a small change rather than creating a whole new GPO.

I currently have a startup script which runs on the PCs I choose. This script runs the setup.exe file and runs the installation without UAC in the background. I would like a way to make sure the users can either see the progress of the install, or be notified of it's completion. I have tried a few ways of introducing a messaging system. This messaging system works when the installation begins, but it does not work for completion. I presume this is because Office 2010 requires a restart as setup.exe is still running in the background.

I also do not want the users PCs to automatically start as they would be working on other software in the mean time.

Here is my script:

```
setlocal

set ProductName=ProPlus

REM Set DeployServer to a network-accessible location containing the Office source files.
set DeployServer=********

REM Set ConfigFile to the configuration file to be used for deployment (required)
set ConfigFile=*******

REM Set LogLocation to a central directory to collect log files.
set LogLocation=*******

IF NOT "%ProgramFiles(x86)%"=="" (goto ARP64)

:ARP64
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432NODE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\%ProductName%
go to END

msg * /time:300 The installation is now beginning!

:DeployOffice
start /wait %DeployServer%\setup.exe /adminfile %deployserver%\Updates\******  
echo %date% %time% Setup ended with error code %errorlevel%. >> %LogLocation%\%computername%.txt

REM If 0 or other was returned, the product was found or another error occurred. Do nothing.

:End
msg * /time:300 The installation is now complete!  Please restart your PC to complete installation.
```

Comment: http://nofusscomputing.com/wiki/public/projects/logongui

Comment: Can you provide some more details as to your current setup? Is this a powershell script that runs under the local system account or....???

Comment: Sorry, I currently have a startup script which runs on the PCs I choose.

This script runs the setup.exe file and runs the installation without UAC in the background.  I would like a way to make sure the users can either see the progress of the install, or be notified of it's completion.  I have tried a few ways of introducing a messaging system.  This messaging system works when the installation begins, but it does not work for completion.  I presume this is because Office 2010 requires a restart as setup.exe is still running in the background.